# Opening an img anchor link at the same location in the next page it is linking to

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm very new at this website making stuff so I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terms - I have tried googling with a bunch of different terms/ideas/wording and I'm not finding anything to help me ask the question more clearly or find examples of what I want

I have an img tag that is an anchor - clicking the image opens a new page (not a new tab, stays in original tab)

I would like the next page that opens with the  to open to the exact location of the img tag. I tried using the `<a id="">, <a href="#id">` thing but I'm not sure if it isn't working bc the "text" that would normally be in the `<a>` is actually an `<img>`

I am trying to create a flip-book style type thing with extremely limited javascript knowledge - I have some javascript that makes it look like you are "turning a page" (just flipping it on the y axis) on the img itself, but when you click the img to go to the next page it just loads at the top of the page and looks messy (have to scroll down to see the img again, and click again)

Including the html/javascript but let me know if more info is needed!

```
<!--this is the page-flip javascript-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../flip-master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
   
<script>
    $(function()
    $(".flip").flip({
    trigger: 'click'});});
</script>
```

````
<main class="flip">
    <div class="front">
    <img src="../images/sketchbook3.jpg" alt="sketchbook page">
    </div> <!--this is where i would like the page to open to upon loading, 
the idea being clicking on the page "opens" to the next page, until the end 
of the "book" . each flip is two images on one page, there are multiple pages
to make up the book-->

    <div class="back">
    <a href="sketchbook3.html"><img src="../images/sketchbook4.jpg" alt="sketchbook page with click to next page"></a>
    </div> 
</main>
```
````

Comment: You want it to open in the same page, or a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash in the `href` URL:

```
<a href="sketchbook3.html#imgid">
```

Where `imgid` is the ID of the element that you want to scroll to on the `sketchbook3.html` page.